# How to detect what app is opened currently in Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-animation, flutter-test

I'm building a Flutter app which simply gives notification while we enter into Instagram.

Is there any way to check if Instagram is opened or not in Flutter?

Any answers will be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: What are you building? A notification system?

Comment: If I open instagram , my app should notify to not watch reels , just creating for fun

Answer (score 0):

You can use this plugin [usage_stats](https://pub.dev/packages/usage_stats)

```
List<UsageInfo> list = await UsageStats.queryUsageStats(startDate, endDate);
```

and check if

```
  List<UsageInfo> appList = [];
    
        for (var i in list) {
              if (listOfApps.contains(i.packageName)) {
                if (!appList.contains(i)) {
                  appList.add(i);
                }
              }
            }
        
        
         for (var usageStats in appList) { 
          if(DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch) >=  int.parse(usageStats.lastTimeUsed!) + 1000)
        {
                      //Instagram is opened
        }
        }
        const List<String> listOfApps = [
        
          'com.instagram.android', // android package name of instagram
        ];
```

Hope its helpfull